# Using google polymer, how to get the width of an element

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

Please let me ask a very elementary technique. Namely how to get the current width of a polymer element. I tried the following code. Howerver it did not work.

template

```
    <template> 
    <paper-input id="id1"></paper-input>
    <button on-tap="ontap">ontap</button>
    </template>
```

polymer function

```
   ontap:function(){alert (this.$.id1.width);}
```

On the web browser, the width of the paper-input element looks same as the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this.$.id1.clientWidth`. `clientWidth` will not include padding and border if you want then also to be included in your width use `offsetWidth`

> clientWidth will round the value to an integer. If you need a fractional value, use element.getBoundingClientRect().

`this.$.id1.getBoundingClientRect().width`  In case you are using inline styling then `this.$.id1.style.width` will also work.

Reference links: [clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)
                 [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)
[getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)